# Ansible Kerberos Name or service not known

Tags: windows, ansible

I've been encountering the problem for 3 days about setting up Ansible on CentOs (control machine) to work with Windows host.

I ran ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 from [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1) to configure Windows host. To ensure WinRM is setting up correctly I also used another Windows to verify two things:

- Run `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 'win1.domain.local' -Port 5985/5986`
- Run `Test-WsMan -ComputerName 'win1.domain.local' -Port 5985/5986`

From the testing Windows based control machine everything looks fine. I managed to create a PSSession and remotely executed script.

From a CentOs machine I use telnet to test port 5985 and 5986 which is listening.

My group_vars/win.yml is as follows:

```
ansible_user: user@domain.local
ansible_password: Password
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

My host is just a FQDN of a machine like below

```
[win]
win1.domain.local
```

My command to test

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -vvvv
```

My playbook is very simple. It's just to check C: directory on target Windows host. So far I always encounter the issue:

```
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<win1.domain.local> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: user@domain.local on PORT 5986 TO win1.domain.local
calling kinit with subprocess for principal user@domain.local
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py:299: UserWarning: Function <unbound method HTTPKerberosAuth.__init__> does not contain optional arg force_preemptive, check installed version with pip list
  % (str(function), name))
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py:299: UserWarning: Function <unbound method HTTPKerberosAuth.__init__> does not contain optional arg delegate, check installed version with pip list
  % (str(function), name))
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py:299: UserWarning: Function <unbound method HTTPKerberosAuth.__init__> does not contain optional arg send_cbt, check installed version with pip list
  % (str(function), name))
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py:299: UserWarning: Function <unbound method HTTPKerberosAuth.__init__> does not contain optional arg principal, check installed version with pip list
  % (str(function), name))
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py:299: UserWarning: Function <unbound method HTTPKerberosAuth.__init__> does not contain optional arg sanitize_mutual_error_response, check installed version with pip list
  % (str(function), name))
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py:299: UserWarning: Function <unbound method HTTPKerberosAuth.__init__> does not contain optional arg hostname_override, check installed version with pip list
  % (str(function), name))
fatal: [win1.domain.local]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "kerberos: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='win01-wmy4anstz.daa.local', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f30681818d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I did test the kerberos ticket with my account user@domain.local and didn't see any issue.

Below is my packages's version

- Ansible: 2.8.0
- Pywinrm: 0.3.0
- pykerberos: 1.2.1
- requests-kerberos: 0.12.0

Comment: Did you follow the error message recommendation ? `pip list | grep pywinrm` => according to [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#what-is-winrm) you should have "pywinrm>=0.3.0"`

Comment: @Zeitounator yes pywinrm is 0.3.0

Comment: Then the next step is probably to go through [troubleshouting kerberos doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#troubleshooting-kerberos), more specifically this comment: `The forward and reverse DNS lookups are working properly in the domain. To test this, ping the windows host by name and then use the ip address returned with nslookup. The same name should be returned when using nslookup on the IP address.`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on one of our windows 2016 server and went through the troubleshooting guide with no success.

In the end I figured out that it was an issue with the server name case. in my inventory file I had it as-

```
hosts:
  server-win01.domain.local
```

ping to server-win01.domain.local was fine.
When I did a reverse lookup the value returned was: Server-Win01.domain.local. One of our staff named with capital case in the Active Directory DNS. When I changed the host name to

```
hosts:
  Server-Win01.domain.local
```

ansible could find the host and the playbook executed fine.